# Trouble with hover menu on a link

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a link (`<a></a>`) that contains an image, when the link is hovered over that a hover menu appears below it(in this case, just one button). The button that appears, I wish to have a link on it.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="My_Image.jpg" width="420" height="280" />
  <ul>
      <a><li>Buy</li></a>
  </ul>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  padding: 5px; margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
a ul{
  padding: 0px; margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  width: 100%;
}
a ul li{
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover ul {
  left: 0;
}
```

My trouble is that when I add the link (`a`) tags inside the `ul` tag the css formatting for the `ul` and all its descendants don't pick up anymore. I hope this is clear enough, let me know if you need me to explain some more.

Comment: You can't nest links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first comment to Adrian, you want the link text to display on top of the image, and upon hovering over the image, a buy button will display beneath the image.  Assuming that, this might work:

```
div {
    padding: 5px; margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
div ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
div ul li{
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div ul li a{
    position: relative;
}
div ul li a span{
    position: absolute;
}
div ul li button{
    visibility: hidden;
}
div ul li:hover button{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and the HTML something like:

```
<div>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="My_Image.jpg" width="420" height="280" /><span>Description</span></a>
        <br/><button>Buy Image 1</button>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="My_Image.jpg" width="420" height="280" /><span>Description</span></a>
        <br/><button>Buy Image 2</button>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Syntax is "incorrect". Block elements in inline elements are forbidden by **specification**.
If you need to create an List based menu, set the "Sub menu" after the Link-Tag:

```
 <ul>
      <li>
           <a href="#">Your Link</a>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sublink</a></li>
           </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: _“Block elements in inline elements are forbidden by specification”_ – not in HTML5 they ain’t, at least not in general – `ul` in `a` _is_ valid HTML5. (But having an `a` as _child_ of an `ul` is still incorrect.)

Comment: I am trying to achieve photos with links on them, to be like inline elements just adjusting around itself. But I wish to have a button appear below the image if its hovered over. How could I acheive this?

Comment: I have had a elements child of a ul. It worked fine. It was a ul with an a child. This one has an extra "a" tag, a > ul > a